# Svn update/cleanup error

Tags: svn, staging

When I run svn update on staging I get:

```
-bash-3.2$ svn update
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
-bash-3.2$ svn cleanup
svn: Error at entry 1 in entries file for '.':
svn: Invalid value for field 'keep-local'
```

There is something wrong with the entries file? Doesn't that contain the UUIDs for the repository? Can't I just rebuild the UUID's for the repo by running:

```
$ svnadmin setuuid /var/svn/repos (on staging for me)
```

what are the risks associated with this?

Comment: Did you move your repository from the other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by abandoning the repository and making a new one. Make sure to copy the files across. Also NEVER EVER mess with the UUIDs or the entries file.